# Vue.js 3: Component Does not render when object value is changed from a method emitted by a child component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have the following three vue.js 3 components:

1)HomeView (Parent)

2)SubItems1 (Child)

3)Item1SideBar (Another Child)

There are a few others but they are not relevant to this support request.

SubItems1 accepts a prop (an object with property "code"): Item1ActiveCode

```
<SubItems1 :item1ActiveCode = item1ActiveCode />
```

Item1SideBar emits a method with an object:

```
<a href="#" @click="loadItem12()"><strong>Item 1 2</strong></a>

            loadItem12() {
                this.item1ActiveCode.code = 2
                this.$emit('load-item-1-2', this.item1ActiveCode)
            }
```

item1ActiveCode is set with that emitted object when the emitted "loadItems12" is fired in the parent HomeView. item1ActiveCode is passed as a prop to SubItems1 child component in the parent HomeView component. However, when loadItems12 is called and item1ActiveCode is set to a new object, component HomeView does not rerender (it is supposed to rerender and pass the new item1ActiveCode prop to the child component SubItems1). Below is the code help is very much appreciated :-) and thank you in advance...

The code:

HomeView (Parent Component):

```
<template>
    <HeaderComponent @active-side-bar="activeSideBar" />
    <div style="display: flex;">
        <Item1SideBar 
        @load-item-1-2 = "loadItem12"  
        v-show = "sideBar1Flag" />
        <Item2SideBar v-show = "sideBar2Flag" />
        <Item3SideBar v-show = "sideBar3Flag" />
        <SubItems1 :item1ActiveCode = item1ActiveCode />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import HeaderComponent from '../components/HeaderComponent'
import Item1SideBar from '../components/Item1SideBar'
import Item2SideBar from '../components/Item2SideBar'
import Item3SideBar from '../components/Item3SideBar'
import SubItems1 from '../components/SubItems1'
import {ref} from 'vue'

export default {
    name: 'HomeView',
    components: {
        HeaderComponent,
        Item1SideBar,
        Item2SideBar,
        Item3SideBar,
        SubItems1
    },
    setup() {
        const sideBar1Flag = ref(true)
        const sideBar2Flag = ref(false)
        const sideBar3Flag = ref(false)
        const item1ActiveCode = ref({ code: -1})

        function activeSideBar (flags) {
            if(flags.sideBar1Flag === true) {
                sideBar1Flag.value = true
                sideBar2Flag.value = false
                sideBar3Flag.value = false
            }

            else if(flags.sideBar2Flag === true) {
                sideBar1Flag.value = false
                sideBar2Flag.value = true
                sideBar3Flag.value = false
            }

            else if(flags.sideBar3Flag === true) {
                sideBar1Flag.value = false
                sideBar2Flag.value = false
                sideBar3Flag.value = true
            }
        }

        function loadItem12(item1ActiveCodeArg) {
            item1ActiveCode.value = item1ActiveCodeArg
            console.log(item1ActiveCode.value.code)
        }

        return {
            activeSideBar: activeSideBar,
            loadItem12: loadItem12,
            sideBar1Flag: sideBar1Flag.value,
            sideBar2Flag: sideBar2Flag.value,
            sideBar3Flag: sideBar3Flag.value,
            item1ActiveCode: item1ActiveCode.value
        }
    },
    created () {
        this.item1ActiveCode.code = 1
    }
}
</script>
```

SubItems1 (Child Component):

```
<template>
    <h1 v-show="item11Flag.value">Item 1 1</h1>
    <h1 v-show="item12Flag.value">Item 1 2</h1>
    <h1 v-show="item13Flag.value">Item 1 3</h1>
</template>

<script>
import {ref} from 'vue'

export default {
    name: 'SubItems1',
    props: {
        item1ActiveCode: Object
    },
    setup() {
        const item11Flag = ref(false)
        const item12Flag = ref(false)
        const item13Flag = ref(false)

        return {
            item11Flag: item11Flag,
            item12Flag: item12Flag,
            item13Flag: item13Flag
        }
    },
    created () {
        console.log(this.item1ActiveCode)
        console.log(this.item1ActiveCode)
        if (this.item1ActiveCode === 1){
            console.log('Bingo!')
            item11Flag.value = true
            item12Flag.value = false
            item13Flag.value = false
        }

        else if(this.item1ActiveCode.code === 2) {
            console.log('Asrar Binko!')
            item11Flag.value = false
            item12Flag.value = true
            item13Flag.value = false 
        }
        
         else if(this.props.item1ActiveCode.code === 3)
             item13Flag.value = true 
    }
}
</script>
```

Item1SideBar (child component):

```
<template>
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <h3>Item 1</h3>
        </div>

        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <li>
                <a href="#" @click="loadItem11()"><strong>Item 1 1</strong></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" @click="loadItem12()"><strong>Item 1 2</strong></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" @click="loadItem13()"><strong>Item 1 3</strong></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Item1Sidebar',
        data() {
            return {
                item1ActiveCode: {
                    code: -1
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            loadItem11() {
                this.item1ActiveCode.code = 1
                this.$emit('load-item-1-1', this.item1ActiveCode)
            },
            loadItem12() {
                this.item1ActiveCode.code = 2
                this.$emit('load-item-1-2', this.item1ActiveCode)
            },
            loadItem13() {
                this.item1ActiveCode.code = 3
                this.$emit('load-item-1-3', this.item1ActiveCode)
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scope>
#sidebar{
    height: 90.2vh;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 7%;
    left: 0;
}
a, a:hover, a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;

}

#sidebar {
    background: #1BCE73;
 
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: black;
    color: #1BCE73;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px;
    color: black;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
}

</style>
```

Comment: *component HomeView does not rerender* what happens instead? is there an error in the browser console perhaps?

Comment: No there are no errors, but I am expecting the component under HomView particularly SubItems1 to rerender with the new prop passed after firing loadItems12 in parent component this will change SubItems1 compoent to present some thing different in the browser, that it is what I am expecting. I am new to vue.js. Isn't the change to the object item1ActiveCode in loadItems12 should trigger the component to rerender (HomeView) thus passing a new prop to child component (SubItems1) and causing the presentation on the browser to change?

Comment: Or my expectation is wrong and I should do some thing different to trigger rerendering.

Comment: does the ouptut of the console.log look correct?

Comment: console.log(this.item1ActiveCode) executes and it prints the object --> { code: 2 } -which is correct- which is the code that needs to be passed as a prop to SubItems1 component, that prop should cause this component to present <h1>Item 1 2</h1> instead of <h1>Item 1 1</h2> provided that the parent component renrenders and causes all its children to rerender having SubItems1 rerender with the new prop value obtained from the object passed as a prop (item1ActiveCode). If I understood the framework correctly, otherwise I need to make changes.

Comment: do you understand that `created` is called once ... so a change to the value of the prop item1ActiveCode in SubItems1 does nothing - also since item1ActiveCode is an object, it won't ever be 1 2 or 3 ... item1ActiveCode.code will be one of those values though (that's just a typo in the first if condition though)

Comment: you could use *computed* values for `item11Flag` etc ... like `item11Flag() { return this.item1ActiveCode.code === 1 }`

Comment: I am very new to vue.js 3 can you please elaborate more but birefly :-)

Comment: do you know what `computed` values are in vuejs - your `SubItems1`  component isn't using the new composition API, so it's the same as vue2 - are you familiar with vue 2?